# Check if a type is defined via static_assert?

Tags: c++, c++20, static-assert, compile-time-constant

I have a situation where I have an enum that defines a list of jobs.

```cpp
enum class job_t
{
  a,
  b,
  c,
};
```

Elsewhere I have classes that subclass an interface like

```cpp
class job_interface
{
  public:
    virtual job_t get_job_type(void) const = 0;
    /* ... other methods snipped for simplicity */
}
```

What I want to do is verify for each value of the `job_t` enum that a class exists that subclasses `job_interface` with the same name. I have access to [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum) so I am wondering if it's possible to translate the enum values to compile time strings and then detect if they're valid typenames via `static_assert`. It would also be nice if I could verify those classes were decendants of `job_interface`

Any suggestions on how I might achieve this?

Comment: it coul be possible with the usage of #define. include all job implementations into a single file. where each includes defines a constant.
You can then check if all constants are defined

Comment: You cannot check for the existance of a class with a `static_assert`: Either the class is there and you could make the `static_assert` work, no problem, or it's not there and the use of the type in the `static_assert` results in a compiler error, but not one caused by the assertion failing. That is if you can even get a list of enum constant names which would require you listing it in a suitable way (could be an X-macro to avoid repetition). This may be simpler for a template with a default implementation suitable for detection and specializations for every enum constant...

Comment: You cannot check that a class *exists*, you can only check that its definition is visible. And you cannot do this from any kind of string representation of its name. IOW if you need to check that `a` is defined, you need to write a piece of code that hardcodes the identifier `a` somewhere (or at least pulls one from a preprocessor macro).

Comment: You are mixing compile time and runtime concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifier names can't be obtained from strings, even if they're compile time. The best you can do is macros, e.g. with [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

```
#define JOB_IDS \
    X(a) \
    X(b) \
    X(c)
```

To define the enum

```
#define X(id) id,
enum class job_t {
    JOB_IDS
};
#undef X
```

Checking for existence is a bit hard. Checking for completeness is easier, which should suffice for your case. To check for completeness of a type `T`, we SFINAE on `sizeof(T)`

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto is_complete(T*) -> decltype(!sizeof(T))
{
    return true;
}

constexpr auto is_complete(void*)
{
    return false;
}
```

Then bundle the completeness check together with the base class check

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto check(T*) -> decltype(!sizeof(T))
{
    return std::is_base_of_v<job_interface, T>;
}

constexpr auto check(void*)
{
    return false;
}
```

Finally, we abuse the fact that `struct a*` is valid regardless of whether `a` is defined or not

```
#define X(id) \
static_assert(check((struct id*)nullptr), #id" has to be defined and inherit from job_interface");
JOB_IDS
#undef X
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9zo9TnaP).